# Apache-tomcat & laravel route not working properly

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat, laravel

I have Apache-tomcat server,  have to run Laravel applications on it.
I  added JavaBridge to apache-tomcat\webapps\ and c/p files ("JavaBridge.jar", "php-script.jar", "php-servlet.jar" to apache-tomcat\lib).
When tested in browser localhost:8080/JavaBridge it opens the page of JavaBridge.
I added a php folder to it, and created a phpinfo(). In browser localhost:8080/JavaBridge/php/testing.php it opened the info page of installed version of php on computer. When laravel was installed and opened in browser (localhost:8080/JavaBridge/php/laravel/public) it opens the welcome page of laravel.
Everything works nice and smoothly to this point.
Then i added a ExtJS view, a control for loading data and set it up in route.

```
Route::get('company/load_company', 'companyController@load');
Route::get ('/', function()
{
    return View::make('company');
});
```

Now everything was tested in XAMPP and it works great, no errors.
But in tomcat i get the ExtJS view, but the data didn't load.
When i follow the link in console to see where the error is, i receive an error from apache-tomcat.

The error is:

```
HTTP Status 404 - JavaBridge/php/Test/public/company/load_company
type status report
mesage
description The request resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat 7
```

As i said in XAMPP it works, but in tomcat not.
How can i make it work in tomcat?